# topology - triangle inequality

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In my homework, I have this question:

> Given points $u,v,w,x$ in a metric space $(X,d)$, prove that
>
> $$|d(u,v)-d(w,x)|≤d(u,w)+d(v,x).$$

Use this result to prove that:

> For sequences $\{x_n \}$,$\{y_n\}$ in $X$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=x \in X$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} ⁡y_n=y \in X$,  it holds $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,y_n )=d(x,y)$

I think I have to use the triangle inequality to prove the first part, but I don't know how to get started.

Comment: To show that $\lvert A - B \rvert \leqslant C$, show $A - B \leqslant C$, and $B - A \leqslant C$. (And here, you show that by showing $A \leqslant B+C$ resp. $B \leqslant A+C$.)

Answer (score 1):

To show that $$|d(u,v)-d(w,x)|≤d(u,w)+d(v,x)$$ try to show two inequalities, namely $$d(u,v)≤d(u,w)+d(w,x)+d(v,x)$$ and $$d(w,x)≤d(u,w)+d(u,v)+d(v,x)$$ Both can be shown by applying the triangle inequality twice.

To deduce the second property about sequences, apply the result with $x=x, v=x_n, w=y,$ and $u=y_n$.